# hilbert separable

Tags: functional-analysis

Hi I have two questions related to functional analysis :

1) is every Hilbert space separable (if not what known counterexample to keep in mind)

2) For an function from a hilbert $H$ to $\mathbb{R}$ admitting a weakgradient, is it true that the weak gradient vanishes at minimum points.

Answer (score 2):

1) No there are not always separable.

If you want a counterexample, you can take $$\ell^2(\mathbb R)=\{(x_y)\in{\mathbb R}^{\mathbb{R}},\ \sum_{y\in \mathbb R} {x_y}^2<+\infty\}$$

2) I will think about a second one and edit if I find an answer.

Comment: If you don't allow your sequences to be negative (and, usually, other complex numbers), you won't have a vector space.